# Transfer address book from Lotus Notes to Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, lotus-notes

Is there a way to transfer the address book (contacts) from Lotus Notes 8.0 to Microsoft Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

Just select the contacts in domino directory use file/export choose csv then file/import/"other address book" in outlook.

Comment: This works, I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [Transend Migrator](http://www.transend.com/products_transend_migrator.asp).  A license costs about $50 if I recall correctly.  There's a free trial as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the number of contacts that you have, but I use MemoToo (http://memotoo.com) to store all my contacts in the cloud. That was I can have the same contacts on any client, mobile or desktop, Mac or Windows.

MemoToo is free for 50 contacts, but as I have over 2000 I oped to pay the £12 for a years unlimited subscription.